# Setting Object Properties using Reflection and Annotation in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing, reflections

I have these 4 classes -

1. Component.java -> which will be annotated using custom annotation,
2. Properties.java -> the annotation class
3. Utilities.java -> class where the annotation is used
4. AnnotationProcessor.java -> where the annotation logic using reflection is built
   What I want is, based on the annotation, I will set a property of the Component object.
   This is my code -

//class which will be annotated using custom annotation

> ```
> public class Component {
> private String name;
> private String id;
>
> public String getId() {
>     return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(String id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
> public String getName() {
>     return name;
> }
> public void setName(String name) {
>     this.name = name;
> }
> ```

//annotation class

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Properties {
    String compName();
}
```

//class where the annotation is used

```
public class Utility {

@Properties(compName = "myName")
Component comp1;

@Properties(compName = "myPassword")
Component comp2;

public void login() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException {
    comp1 = new Component();
    comp2 = new Component();

    comp1.setId("1111");
    comp2.setId("2222");
    AnnotationProcessor annotationProcessor = new AnnotationProcessor();
    annotationProcessor.process(this, comp1);
    annotationProcessor.process(this, comp2);
}}
```

//class where the annotation is processed

```
public class AnnotationProcessor {
    public void process (Object callingClass, Component c){
    System.out.println("In AnnotationProcessor:process");

    Class<? extends Object> aClass = callingClass.getClass();
    Field[] declaredFields = aClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field: declaredFields) {
        if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Properties.class)){
          if (field.get(callingClass) != null) { //Added newly
            Properties annotation = field.getAnnotation(Properties.class);
            String val = annotation.compName();
            c.setName(val);
            field.set(callingClass, c); //Added newly
            System.out.println("For field " + field.getName() + ", component id is : " + c.getId() + " and name is : --> " + c.getName());
            break; //Added newly
        }

    }
}
```

}

I want to achieve to set the name of "comp1" to be "myName" and name of "comp2" to be "myPassword". Basically, the output I expect is this -

```
For field comp1, component id is : 1111 and name is : --> myName
For field comp2, component id is : 2222 and name is : --> myPassword
```

But the actual output is this (after //added newly changes)-

```
In AnnotationProcessor:process
For field comp1, component id is : 1111 and name is : --> myName
In AnnotationProcessor:process
For field comp1, component id is : 2222 and name is : --> myName
```

My problem is, how to assign the "name" of the component as per the annotation for that component object only and not for all the fields the Utility class has. I feel there is some if condition in the middle that might help achieve this, but not able to find it out.

Comment: Check if the field value is `null`, otherwise skip the field. And `break` after the first field is set.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn
Could you please explain what you mean by if the field is `null`. I wrote this and this is never true - `if(field == null) `.

Comment: `if (field.get(callingClass) != null) {...; field.set(callingClass, c); break;}`

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem - 
`if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Properties.class)) {
     if (field.get(callingClass) != null) { //Added newly
         Properties annotation = field.getAnnotation(Properties.class);
         String val = annotation.compName();
         c.setName(val);
         field.set(callingClass, c); //Added newly
         System.out.println("For field " + field.getName() + ", component id is : " + c.getId() + " and name is : --> " + c.getName());
           break; //Added newly
      }}}}`

Comment: Now output is - `In AnnotationProcessor:process
For field comp1, component id is : 1111 and name is : --> myName
In AnnotationProcessor:process
For field comp1, component id is : 2222 and name is : --> myName`

Comment: You forgot the `break`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I updated the original post with //Added newly comment. I did add the `break`, after the `sysout`.

Comment: Ok, `(field.get(callingClass) != null)` should be `(field.get(callingClass) == c)`. remove the `field.set(callingClass, c);`

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn. Its perfect, works like a charm now !

Comment: Maybe, just one more question. Is there any way to get the `Object callingClass` from the `Component c` ? That is, can my process method be like this to achieve same result ?
`public void process (Component c)`

Comment: The parameter name `callingClass` is misleading, as it is not the class but an instance you’re passing. So, no, you can’t get that object in a different way. But what is this feature all about? Is writing `@Properties(compName = "myPassword")`, plus `annotationProcessor.process(this, comp2);` in the constructor, really an improvement over writing just `comp2.setName("myPassword");` in the constructor?